# remove strong tag and its content from string

Tags: javascript

I'm having below string with this html, i'm wondering how can i remove/filter all strong tags and its text from the string?

**html**

```
<p>
    <br>
    2-3 spsk græsk yoghurt, gerne 10 % 
    <strong>Dressing: </strong>
    <br>
    1 lille spsk god mayonnaise
    <br>
    1-2 tsk æbleeddike 
    <br>
    1-2 tsk honning 
    <br>
    himalayasalt og friskkværnet hvid peber
    <br>
</p>
```

so far i have this, but only seem to remove strong tag if it is at the top

```
var ingredientsArray = ingredients.split('<br>').map(it => it.trim()).filter(it => !!it && !it.startsWith('<strong>'));
```

Comment: Why not manipulate the DOM?

Comment: If it really is a string, put the string to a document fragment as HTML, get a reference to  `strong`s with a DOM parser method, remove them, and convert back to string if needed.

Comment: What is the end goal? If you convert to DOM elements for the removal, some of the format of the HTML may change when converting back. Do you actually need to convert back, or is the result going to be added to the DOM anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to manipulate the string, apply a CSS rule to wherever this is going to be put into the DOM:

```
strong { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DOM API for this:

```js
function stripStrong(html) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = html;
    [...span.getElementsByTagName('strong')].reverse().forEach( 
        strong => strong.parentNode.removeChild(strong)
    );
    return span.innerHTML;
}

var html = `<p>
    <br>
    2-3 spsk græsk yoghurt, gerne 10 % 
    <strong>Dressing: </strong>
    <br>
    1 lille spsk god mayonnaise
    <br>
    1-2 tsk æbleeddike 
    <br>
    1-2 tsk honning 
    <br>
    himalayasalt og friskkværnet hvid peber
    <br>
</p>`;

console.log(stripStrong(html));
```

Note that this also works if the `strong` tag has attributes, styles, is nested with other `strong` tags, etc... something that regular expressions can have trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing the string as HTML would most likely be the way to go, depending on what the goal is ?

```js
var ingredients = '<p><br>2-3 spsk græsk yoghurt, gerne 10 % <strong>Dressing: </strong><br>1 lille spsk god mayonnaise<br>1-2 tsk æbleeddike <br>1-2 tsk honning <br>himalayasalt og friskkværnet hvid peber<br></p>';

var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(ingredients, 'text/html');

[].forEach.call(doc.querySelectorAll('strong'), function (item) {
    item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
});

document.body.innerText = '<pre>' + doc.body.innerHTML + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use regex for this:

```
var ingredientsArray = ingredients.replace(/<strong>[\s\S]*?<\/strong>/g, '')
     .split('<br>').map(it => it.trim()).filter(Boolean);
```

Comment: I believe that if the string contains more than one `<strong>`, this will remove everything from the beginning of the first one to the end of  the last.

Comment: @torazaburo you can fix it by adding `?` after `*` for regex to be non greedy